# pthreads - deadlock on pthread_cond_wait

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, deadlock

I'm trying to learn how to use threads in c and I made a program that counts the number of lines in a file(s). The program creates a thread per each file so that different files can be counted concurrently. 
The problem I am having is that the program blocks, which makes me think that deadlock has occurred. I am hoping someone can shed some light as to why this is happening. The test run involved 10 text files. I also omitted error checking in my code below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>
struct thefiles * mailbox;
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t flag =  PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
struct thefiles {
  char    *name;
  int linecount;
};
void *count_words(void *a) {
  char    *buffer;
  int          fd;
  size_t    total;
  int   count = 0;
  int    size = 0;
  struct thefiles *fls = malloc(sizeof(*fls));

  fd = open(a, O_RDONLY);
  size   = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
  buffer =  malloc(size);
  lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
  read(fd, buffer, size);
  while (*buffer) {
    if ( *buffer == '\n' )
      count++;
    buffer++;
        }
  fls->name = a;
  fls->linecount = count;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  if (mailbox != NULL)
    pthread_cond_wait(&flag, &lock);
  mailbox = fls;
  pthread_cond_signal(&flag);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[argc]) {
  int                i;
  int        total = 0;
  pthread_t   *threads;
  struct thefiles *fls;
  threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*(--argc));
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, count_words, argv[i+1]);
  }
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  while (argc) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&flag, &lock);
    total += mailbox->linecount;
    free(mailbox);
    mailbox = NULL;
    pthread_cond_signal(&flag);
    argc--;
  }
  printf("%d\n", total);
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }
}
```

Comment: the `main` thread never unlocks the mutex. So if `main` grabs the mutex, then a worker thread tries to grab it, the worker thread blocks, then `main` does `pthread_join` so it blocks waiting on the worker to finish... now both `main` and the worker are blocked waiting on each other --> deadlock

Comment: I just added     pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock) right below pthread_cond_signal(&flag) in main and the program still blocking

Comment: You never check the return values from `open()`, `lseek()`, and `read()`.  You're also treating the entire contents of the file as a NUL-terminated string, but `read()` doesn't NUL-terminate anything.  So your `while (*buffer)` is going to go off into Never Never Land.  And you don't `free()` the allocated `buffer` to boot.

Comment: I believe unlocking a mutex more times than it's been locked is UB.. it should at least be after the `while` loop. But this looks overly complicated to me anyway. Why does `main` need to lock a mutex, wait on a signal, signal, ..? In `main` I would simply launch the worker threads then join on them immediately,, and each worker thread would open its file, count its lines, lock a mutex to update the total number of lines, unlock the mutex, then exit. No need for signals at all. Then after all threads have joined, `main` can print out the total # of lines or whatever.

Comment: @AndrewHenle as I stated in my post I omitted error checking for the sake of brevity

Comment: @yano I agree. It is overly complicated but I am trying to gain insight into using threads and the common problems that arise. I actually implemented this program without using any mutex. I simply have every thread return a pointer to a struct thefiles and read their linecount right after a call to join_thread in main.

Comment: You won't learn how to use condition variables by over complicating things, you are archiving quite the contrary. You only use conditional variables when you **need** them, not when you want to.

Comment: The worst thing you can do to learn about threads is to throw them at a problem that doesn't require them. Counting line numbers in different files in parallel is a fine example, but I fail to see what the waits and signals do for you here (unless I'm misunderstanding your task). A _condition_ variable is just that, a variable that changes according to some condition. There's really no events/conditions that occur from counting line numbers in a file. Now, if you were counting line #s in 10 files and wanted to do something when 5 were done, that would be a condition to look for.

Comment: @yano actually I was going to have each linecount value displayed along with the current total as soon as each thread was done but then I had this problem.

Comment: do that work in the thread. Each thread counts it's lines, prints it out, locks the mutex, adds its count to the total count and prints out the current total, unlocks the mutex, exit. `main` just sits back and waits. Or you can have main do the same work as the worker threads if you want before it joins on them. Bottom line, I think you'll be better served coming up with a different example that _needs_ condition variables. This does not.

Comment: @yano, you said, "the `main` thread never unlocks [`lock`]." But, it _does_ unlock `lock`.  It unlocks it by calling `pthread_cond_wait(&flag, &lock)`.

Comment: @jameslarge ahh yes, you are correct.. whoops. However, when `pthread_cond_wait` returns, the mutex is locked again, so once `argc` reaches 0 the same possibility for deadlock is there.

Comment: Note:  I should have said "... _temporarily_ unlocks it" because, of course, `pthread_cond_wait(&flag, &lock)` will re-lock `lock` before returning.  The lock will be locked when the main thread tries to `join()` the other threads.  Better hope they've all died by then.

Comment: Never call `pthread_cond_wait` without first checking to see if the think you are going to wait for has already happened. That's the point of locking the mutex.

Comment: getting random downvotes now? what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2):

You have at least the following problems:

- In your loop in `main()`, you don't check whether `mailbox` is NULL when `pthread_cond_wait()` returns. The function `pthread_cond_wait()` can return at any time, even if `pthread_cond_signal()` has not been called, so you need to account for the case where this happens.
- Similarly, in `count_words()`, you don't check whether `mailbox` has become NULL. `pthread_cond_wait()` should always be called in a `while` loop, along the lines of:

  ```
    while (!condition) {
        pthread_cond_wait()
    }
  ```

Also I recommend checking your error codes - even if you just print the error and exit, it's a lot more educational than staring at a program that's not doing anything :)

Answer (score 1):

You are over complicating things for no reason, you will have a hard time
figuring threading out when you yourself put stones on the way. A reason to use
conditional variables is for when threads must be syncronized, when one
thread can can only continue working, when another has reached some state and both (or more threads) have to
be synchronized. In this case however, no thread depends on the others and
the main thread can happily wait for all workers to end before doing something
useful.

[psmears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50051653/1480131) points out some of the problem in your code. I'd like to expand on
that answer and show you how you can use threads for solving this problem
withput making it too complicated (no signals needed, no mutex needed).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct thefiles {
  char *name;
  int linecount;
  int fo_errno;
};

void *count_lines(void *args)
{
    struct thefiles *data = args;

    FILE *fp = fopen(data->name, "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        data->linecount = -1; // signaling error
        data->fo_errno = errno;
        pthread_exit(0);
    }

    data->linecount = 0;

    char line[1024];
    char *nl;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
    {
        nl = strchr(line, '\n');

        if(nl)
            data->linecount++;
    }

    // last line of file did not end in newline
    if(nl == NULL)
        data->linecount++;

    fclose(fp);

    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s file [file ...]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    struct thefiles *fls = calloc(argc - 1, sizeof *fls);
    if(fls == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pthread_t *ths = calloc(argc - 1, sizeof *ths);

    if(ths == NULL)
    {
        free(fls);
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i)
    {
        fls[i].name = argv[i+1];

        pthread_create(ths + i, NULL, count_lines, fls + i);
    }

    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(ths[i], NULL);
        if(fls[i].linecount == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s: %s\n", argv[0], fls[i].name, strerror(fls[i].fo_errno));
            continue;
        }

        printf("%4d %s\n", fls[i].linecount, fls[i].name);
        total += fls[i].linecount;
    }

    printf("%4d total\n", total);

    free(ths);
    free(fls);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it is much simpler than yours, there is no need for signals and
condition variables etc, The workers do exactly one thing: open the
file, count the lines, store the result in the arguments passed to the thread
and exit. The main thread creates the threads and joins them and prints the
results:

```
$ ./b /etc/fstab a.c b.c aa
  46 /etc/fstab
 124 a.c
  98 b.c
./b: aa: No such file or directory
 268 total

$ wc -l /etc/fstab a.c b.c aa
  46 /etc/fstab
 124 a.c
  98 b.c
wc: aa: No such file or directory
 268 total
```

Of course this is just a simple example, I'd build on this example to exapnd the
usage of the threads, for example calculating the total by the threads
themselves. In this case `total` must be a shared resource and you would need a
mutex to protect it, try implementing that first.

Comment: yes, this is similar to my first implementation of the program which i mentioned in the conversation above with yano. Although the program you made does not count the correct number of lines, I understand the point you are trying to make. I would upvote you but i cant. thanks!

Comment: why do you say my code does not count the correct number of lines? I printed the output of `wc -l` with the same input file, it prints the same as mine.

Comment: not on my end. I ran your program with the 10 files i have and your program counts 994450 and wc counts 994448

Comment: @rhoward really? Before posting I checked it with `wc -l` with many text files, I always got the same result. For which file does my program show a different number to `wc -l`? Is that a binary file?